# How to select data from entity framework without selecting its icollection(foreign table)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatable

I am using C# to select data from my database. Now i have two table, the first one is aspnetuser, the second one is aspnetuserroles, the aspnetuserroles have the foreign key linkage with aspnetuser table, when i perform the following query

```
db.AspNetUsers.ToList()
```

the aspnetroles data will appeared in the aspnetusers data. This will cause my datatable unable to display its data because datatable expect one value in one column parameter. If the aspnet roles data inside that json, it will appear as multiple row and datatable dont accept it.. If i remove that foreign key linkage, my datatable will display without any error.

In this case, what i want is, how to select aspnetusers table without pulling out its foreign table. For eg

```
db.AspNetUsers.Select(x=>x.AspNetUsers).ToList();
```

Comment: did you try by turning off the lazy loading?

Comment: @JSantosh yes lazy loading false solve the problem, mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off the LazyLoading. So that the children will not be fetched automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like this (good for keeping the return object light and leave behind any unwanted columns):

(I have just made up some col name, but you get the idea.)

```
var result = (from a in db.AspNetUsers
              select new AspNetUser { Name = a.Name, 
                           othercol1 = a.othercol1,
                           othercol2 = a.othercol2,
                           }).ToList();
```

Footnote: In reality it is generally not good practice to return the actual db Entity to the front end so you might want to have your own Data Transfer Objects (DTO).

Answer (score 0):

You configured that in the mappings using the Fluent API's methods

- `HasOptional`
- `HasMany`
- `Ignore`

etc. But normally, I create schema-bound views in database and then map that in EF. It works really well in cases when we're only interested in a flattened query without all the joints.

Or use Linq to EF projections as JonhB's answer...

```
var result = (from a in db.AspNetUsers
          select new AspNetUser { Name = a.Name, 
                       ...
                       }).ToList();
```

Just make sure you don't call `ToList` on `db.AspNetUsers` because that would materialize the query on `AspNetUsers` and all it's foreign key references and as result the projection is done in-memory after the query returns